# How To Align th with respect to td value in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

```js
$("#demo").dataTable({

  "data": Data,
  // "sDom": '<lr>t<"F"ip>',
  "sDom": 'Brtip',
  "bInfo": false,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "destroy": true,
  "iDisplayLength": 9,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "responsive": true,
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [0],
    "sTitle": ColumnArray[0],
    "sortable": true,
    "searchable": false, //Scheme Name



    "createdCell": function(th, td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {

      var value = jQuery.isNumeric(cellData);



      if (value === true) {
        $(td).addClass(text_right);
        $(th).addClass(text_right);

      } else {
        $(td).addClass(text_left);
        $(th).addClass(text_right);

      }

    },
    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {

      var SchemeColHTML = CreateDataHTMLSec(data, type, row, meta);
      return SchemeColHTML;
    }

  }];
});
```

i want to align td text with respect to numeric value i am able to align td but how to align the corresponding th  i am using jquery datatable if numeric align th to right or else align th to left